# Working with Shopify API

Tags: python, rest, shopify

Is is possible to create a customer in Shopify via their API? To elaborate, I want to use Shopify to manage my customers and orders and so on. But my website registration page, for a particular reason, isn't on Shopify plathform, it's a separate website-page built only to register my users. So when a user registers, will I be able to insert them into my account in Shopify?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible using the Customers API: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#create

Answer (score 0):

It is possible,

You can find a python sample here,
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/master/test/customer_test.py

Last time, I tried the Shopify API (like 1 year ago) the Python samples on their GitHub page were a bit behind but nevertheless they have a lot of samples in Ruby and other easy to read programming languages and they have a very good documentation.